# Perl : print of $ is empty without \n

Tags: perl

I need help to understand a problem that will probably seem silly to you, that I encounter in the execution of this relatively basic perl script.

I want to extract information from a file in order to fill a hash that will be used later.

Below is an extract of the file used as input :

```
    edit "DNS"
        set category "Network Services"
        set tcp-portrange 53
        set udp-portrange 53
    next
    edit "HTTP"
        set category "Web Access"
        set tcp-portrange 80
    next
    edit "HTTPS"
        set category "Web Access"
        set tcp-portrange 443
    next
    edit "IMAP"
        set category "Email"
        set tcp-portrange 143
    next
    edit "IMAPS"
        set category "Email"
        set tcp-portrange 993
    next
    edit "LDAP"
        set category "Authentication"
        set tcp-portrange 389
    next
```

And here is the code (which is probably not optimal, I'm more than a beginner) used to extract the data from the input:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
 
 use strict;
 use warnings;
  
 my $InFile = "/mnt/c/Users/claidin/OneDrive - Hitachi Vantara/Desktop/Perso/Firewalling/log-rules/import-svc_objet.conf";
 open (InFile,"$InFile") or die "Can't open file\n";
 my $Ligne;
 my %svcDB =(); 
 my $svcname;
 my $service;
 while ($Ligne=<InFile>)
{
if ($Ligne=~ /set\s(.*)\-portrange\s(.*)\n/)
    {
    $service = (uc($1)."_".$2);
    print $service;
    #   print "$service\n";
    }
}
```

my problem concerns the variable `$service` (which will be used as a key to fill the hash I mentioned earlier).

Value of `$service` are only shown when I add I add `\n` to the print (line 18)

example:

```
claidin@PF49BCDO:/mnt/c/Users/claidin/OneDrive-HitachiVantara/Desktop/Perso/Firewalling/log-rules$perlextract-svc-test1.pl
TCP 53
UDP
53
TCP
80
TCP 443
TCP 143
TCP 993
TCP
389
TCP 135
UDP
135
TCP
110
TCP 995
TCD 139
```

If I use the `print` on line 17 I get no return.

I must not have the `\n` set in the variable `$service` to fill the hash, but without the hash is empty.

Could you please explain me this behavior and give me some recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Your file is a Windows text file, by which I means the lines end with Carriage Return (CR) followed by a Line Feed (LF).

On a Windows system, Perl will automatically translate CR LF to LF on read, so you get

```
set tcp-portrange 443␊
```

---

But you are using a Perl built for a unixy system, so it expects lines to end with LF.

No translation occurs, so `print $service;` prints

```
set tcp-portrange 443␍␊
```

---

On this system with this file, `$2` ends with a CR, so `print $service;` prints

```
TCP 53␍
```

Your terminal interprets the CR by moving the cursor to the home position. For example,

```perl
print "abcdef\r123\n";
```

would appear as

```perl
123def
```

So it's not that nothing is printed, it's that all your output was overwritten by your prompt.

---

To fix this, I'd normally suggest using `dos2unix` or similar to convert the file to a unix file. By you're mounting a volume used by Windows directly, so that's not an option without affecting the Windows system.

Normally, I would also suggest that you could replace `chomp;` with `s/\s+\z//;`. You don't use `chomp` here, but you could use `s/\s+\z//;` if you also remove the `\n` from the pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much for your analysis.
The origin of the problem is indeed related to the CR of the windows text file.
For this test I had copied and pasted an extract from a linux file originally.
I have just redone the test with the source file cleaned up identically to the example provided, and the problem no longer exists.


I didn't manage to use s/\s+\z//; instead of chomp (I'm a beginner and didn't know how to adapt my code accordingly)
But the understanding of this problem allows me to reach my goal

Comment: UJsually, you'd use `while ( my $line = <> ) { chomp( $line ); ... }` so you don't have to deal with the trailing line feed. But you could use `while ( my $line = <> ) { $line =~ s/\s+\z//; ... }` to trim all trailing whitespace, incl CR and LF.

Comment: ok great, thank you very much.
I also try dos2unix to convert the windows text file to unix file, and its work fine as well.